# Reading xml file from internet-Cross Origin Request Error on Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, cors

I am trying to read xml file on the internet.It works on IE but does not on Firefox/Chrome.
It gives the error below on Firefox;

***Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxxxx.com/YYYY.xml. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.***

Here is my code;

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("http://xxxxx.com/YYYY.xml");
...........
.........
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

It returns null on the line 
xhttp.responseXML;
in the loadXMLDoc function.

After getting this error I googled the error and tried the code below which makes CORS request. But it also does now work.

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'http://xxxxx.com/YYYY.xml';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

In makeCorsRequest() function, after createCORSRequest() function, xhr.responseText is "" and xhr.ResponseXML is null.In response handler, it gives xhr.onerror.

Could you help me about this error?
Thanks.

UPDATE:

I am trying to test my pages in my computer(localhost). On the IIS in my computer, I enabled the CORS with the web.config below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

On the network tab of the developer tab of Firefox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJfRO.jpg

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on the server? What response headers is it sending? What does the Net tab of your developer tools show? Does it make the HTTP request you expect? Or does it make an OPTIONS preflight request and then give up?

Comment: I am trying to test my pages in my computer(localhost). On the IIS in my computer, I enabled the CORS with the web.config which is explained on the page below

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CORS on the server hosting `http://xxxxx.com/YYYY.xml`, not on the server hosting your HTML document (which is `localhost` in your example).

You can't give yourself permission to access another server.

Comment: It seems CORS is enabled on the remote server http://xxxxx.com/YYYY.xml. Because in the code that I share in my first message,    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url); is not return null in function makeCorsRequest() {
   var url = 'http://xxxxx.com/YYYY.xml';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

Comment: @JesseGuetta — No, that means the **browser** supports CORS. You can't tell if the remote server is giving the browser permission to expose the data you are requesting to JS on your page until the HTTP request is made.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Quentin. I am confusing this topic, Internet Explorer runs the code above successfully and there is not any CORS error. In this situation, can't we say that CORS is enabled on the remote server ?

Comment: I have no idea why it is working in IE, as far as I can tell, it shouldn't. CORS is not enabled on the remote server, your screenshot shows the response headers and Access Control Allow Origin is not among them.